# HTA Script Errors

Tags: hta

I've made a HTA that just links to a website and once you're there you can navigate through several different pages. It's not an application that can change or access anything on the computer.

My problem is when I try to put a frame or an iframe in a page with an external website inside this frame, script errors keep popping up. When I view these same webpages on Internet Explorer 9, no errors show up.

Error Example:
http://i39.tinypic.com/keyfs4.gif

I know HTAs can access the files on a computer and have higher privileges and security over normal pages that are viewed in a browser. Is this the reason script errors show up when on a HTA?

Is there any way I can stop these errors coming up?

Answer (score 1):

Your script has errors. You need to fix them.

The difference is, the Web Browsers a HTML with script errors are less likely to show all script errors. The usual symptom is your script does not run correctly but you're not given any indication as to why.

As a HTA, your same script errors will display as a dialog box. This will tell you why your scripts do not run correctly.

As a personal rule, I generally prefer to code first in HTA so that I can locate and fix errors before deploying them as HTML.

Take the following code example. As a HTA when you click on the Test button it will correctly show "Begin" then it will correctly report your script has a Division by Zero error. As a HTML, in Internet Explorer, the test button will just show "Begin" and then it will abort without giving you any indication why.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script language="VBScript">
    Sub btnTest_onClick
      MsgBox "Begin"
      MsgBox 100 / 0
      MsgBox "End"
    End Sub
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  Click on this button: <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Test"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@BicycleDude - the errors are not located within @user990175's code but within the external website he is loading into an iframe.  So he can't really control the errors that are thrown in 3rd party code.

@user990175 - the issue you're seeing is a result of the third party code using htc's which I'm 90% sure are not supported in hta's, or have special considerations anyway.  Either way you should be able to disable error notifications via the error prompt itself or under Tools > Options > Advanced tab > Browsing section > Dispaly a notification about every script error.

That doesn't mean the functionality will magically work, it just means you won't be prompted with the pesky dialog box.